# Como puedo refrescar un tab desde otro usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Estoy trabajando en una página, donde puede verse un detalle de un ''producto'', pero además de eso, se le puede añadir cierta información (para hacerlo, se hace click en un botón, que abre un nuevo tab con el formulario correspondiente)

Me gustaría, que al finalizar de llenar el segundo formulario, enviarlo, y validar que todo fué correcto, refrescar el tab original (el que abrió este formulario) para que aquí mismo se plasme la información nueva que fué añadida.

He buscado bastante en SO, y no he encontrado mucha información.

¿Es esto posible?

Comment: Hace tiempo tuve un bug que te puede ayudar, esto era, con variables globales, entonces lo que se guardaba en un tab se populaba en todos, pero no te recomiendo el uso de variables globales.Por otro lado, he encontrado esto que igual te da alguna idea de por donde tirar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917753/insert-jquery-object-in-another-browser-tab-with-events

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco muchas gracias por la idea, ahí le pegué una mirada, voy a tenerla en cuenta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes que pasar información puedes usar el [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

---

Si no tienes que pasar ningún tipo de información puedes usar [`BroadcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) o [`SharedWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker)

[`BroadcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) no es compatible con IE ni con Safari

Tab 1:

```
<button>Abrir tab</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ch = new BroadcastChannel('nombreCanal');
    ch.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        if(e.data =="refresh"){
            refresh(); //Tu función para refrescar
        }
    });
</script>
```

Tab 2:

```
//Despues de validar que todo esta ok (success)
var ch = new BroadcastChannel('nombreCanal');
ch.postMessage('refresh');
```

---

Fuente: [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que estaba buscando!